# R "exact" floating point representation

Tags: r, floating-point, precision

How is R deciding to convert 0.099999999999999 into 0.1?

```
> format(0.3/3, digits=17)
[1] "0.099999999999999992"
> format(0.3/3, digits=16)
[1] "0.09999999999999999"
> format(0.3/3, digits=15)
[1] "0.1"
```

Comment: if R rounds to 16 digits, it looks at the 17nth and since it is a 2 it will round to 0.999...
if R rounds to 15 digits, it looks at the 16nth which is a 9. This will result in rounding up to 0.1

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you interested in the technical aspects of the rounding done by `format` (and `print`) or are you asking why 0.3/3 returns this exact floating point number ?

Answer (score 1):

The full decimal expansion of 0.03/3 in IEEE 754 64-bit arithmetic is:

0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625

If the most significant dropped digit is the first 6 it rounds up, giving:

0.099999999999999992

If the most significant dropped digit is the first 1, it rounds down, giving:

0.09999999999999999

If the most significant dropped digit is the last 9 of the block of nines, it rounds up, giving:

0.1

All your results, including the final 0.1, can be explained by assuming decimal rounding to the number of digits you specified.